# how to display xaml textbox suggestions list

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Windows Store app using XAML. I have some textbox controls for input. When the user types using the on-screen keyboard I want to display a suggestions list, like the one that appears in the Mail app for example. This does not display by default. How do I enable it? I have tried setting IsTextPredictionEnabled to True but that made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

I have created a sample app for Windows 8.1 & Windows 8 using just `TextBox`, I was able to get suggestion. Though I am using Windows 8.1, I don't know if that feature is 8.1 exclusive or not. I tested the app in simulator using touch mode. Below given screenshot is of Windows 8 project using VS2012. `IsTextPredictionEnabled` is by default set to `true`.

```
<TextBox Height="200" Width="500"  />
```

[image]

---

<s>You have to use `AutoCompleteBox`.</s>

[Auto-complete box under a text box in Windows 8 / Metro UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967143/auto-complete-box-under-a-text-box-in-windows-8-metro-ui)

[`IsTextPredictionEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.istextpredictionenabled) is used to show spelling suggestions in on-screen keyboard. <s>It's not related to your textbox's possible values.</s>

Comment: I don't want to build my own control using my values for candidates. I just want the built-in functionality that offers candidates based on the installed language pack.

Comment: There's no in-built functionality, otherwise I would have gave you that solution. You can use resources for localization.

Comment: @ Xyroid What I am referring to is the built-in functionality that exists with other apps like Mail and OneNote. When you start to type a word, a list of candidates is displayed (from the installed language pack).

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot? If your are looking for spell checking then use this `IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"`.

Comment: I am unable to upload an image (requires 10 reputation) but if you open the Windows 8 Mail Metro app with a tablet (without attached keyboard) and click reply to any e-mail then start typing on the on-screen keyboard you will see a box displayed under the text with word suggestions (which are derived from the installed language pack).

Comment: If you can't upload an image in question, then upload on http://imgur.com & give me link. I don't own a touch device to test what you are saying.

Comment: Thanks Xyroid for your patience and persistence. I followed your advice and created a sample app which worked correctly so I then set about detecting why my app was not working. Strangely it turned out to be that I had a property InputScope="AlphanumericFullWidth" which prevented the suggestions displaying. Furthermore the setting had no effect, and was therefore unnecessary, as it seems that this value is the default, which makes me suspect that this is therefore a bug.